# Merge [linegraph] and [linechart] tags

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

The two tags [linechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linechart) and [linegraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linegraph) mean the same thing, and it is unclear which to use, so can the two tags be merged?

If you look at the two wikis, the descriptions even use the exact same text. The line chart wiki even already includes line graphs.

**Line Chart:**

> A line chart **or line graph** is a type of chart, which displays information as a series of data points connected by straight line segments.

**Line Graph:**

> A line graph is a type of chart which displays information as a series of data points called markers connected by straight line segments. It shows how something changes in value (as time goes by, or as something else happens).

Both these descriptions are copied from the same [Wikipedia text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_chart).

[linechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linechart) currently has 1,081 questions and [linegraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linegraph) has 255. It seems like line chart is the more commonly used term, so I would chose to keep that one and make line graph into a synonym.

Comment: Is there any real programming question which sole tag can be this tag?

Comment: @Braiam I've been spending some time in the Chart.js tag, so that is where I see them being used. Although there the tags are always accompanied by [chart.js], it still is many times useful to see right away which kind of chart the question is referring to. I've also seen questions with just a main language like Android, C#, R or Java used with one of these chart tags, so it seems like it is used.

Comment: That kind of information is perfect for being included on the title where you can actually specify the context of the question.

Comment: @Braiam Well there definitely is no need for 2 of these tags, so merging them would be a step in the right direction. If you are suggesting that both should be burnated, I think that would need some more research to see how much they are really used. For now though, these 2 tags are just 2 duplicate tags that I think should be merged into 1 tag.